# yaourt -Syu is not working in arch linux

Tags: linux, arch-linux, upgrade, yaourt

I tried `yaourt -Syu` and got this error:

`error: failed to prepare transaction (could not satisfy dependencies)`

`:: Starting full system upgrade...`

`:: nvidia: requires linux<3.11`

how could I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with `yaourt -Syyu`. (or `pacman -Syyu` as root)

If not working, double check:

- if the first mirror in your [mirrorlist](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Mirrors#Enabling_a_specific_mirror) is up-to-date (you may want to swap it for another one)
- if you're using the standard [nvidia package](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/extra/x86_64/nvidia/) (because it's dependencies should be linux<3.12 and linux>=3.11, not linux<3.11)
- <del>if your [pacman.conf](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Pacman#Repositories) file is consistent (ie you don't have both [extra] and [testing] uncommented)</del>

Comment: My bad on that point. (not a testing user, and forgot to rtfm that before writing)